# I brought a second hand I phone 5s tha is registered for beta updates

Tags: iphone, ios, beta-seed-program

Is it possible to go to normal updates or do I need to keep using the updates also how do I update when it wasn't done on my Apple ID

Answer (score 2):

You can use iTunes to restore the device to the last shipping OS.

You could also delete the beta profile and keep the same OS. There's not much preventing you from keeping the beta updates as well.

Really - there's no downside to inheriting a device with beta other than you want to decide now before you put your data on it. You generally can't restore a new backup to an older OS.

Comment: I all ready put my data on before I knew does that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you already put your data on it, and don't want to loose it. Update to the latest beta. Then when the public release comes out, update to that. Then be done with betas.